# How can I get the field information by its name in static method?

Tags: static, getpicklistvalues, getfieldvalue

I tried to write my code like this:

```
public static string getPicklistValues(String fieldApi) {
  List<String> picklistValue = new List<String>();
  Schema.DescribeFieldResult picklist = Customer__c.get(fieldApi).getDescribe();
  List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistData = picklist.getPicklistValues();
  for (Schema.PicklistEntry item : picklistData) {
    picklistValue.add(item.getLabel());
  }
  return JSON.serialize(picklistValue);
}
```

But I cannot deploy this code into org. System shows this error:
`Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: Object Customer__c.get(String)`

Is there anyway to approach this case. Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, as the error is pointing out, is the `Customer__c.get(fieldApi)` part of the `Schema.DescribeFieldResult picklist = Customer__c.get(fieldApi).getDescribe();` line.

`Customer__c`, all on its own like that, is referencing the *class* that Salesforce auto-generates (which inherits from the `SObject` class) when you created that custom SObject. Since SObject doesn't have any static methods, `<SObject name here>.<method name here>()` will always fail compilation because `<class name>.<method name>()` is how you call static methods.

Instead, you want to be working with the SObject Describe Info.

`Schema.DescribeFieldResult picklist = Schema.SObjectType.Customer__c.fields.getMap().get(fieldApi).getDescribe();`
or
`Schema.DescribeFieldResult picklist = Customer__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldApi).getDescribe();`

Comment: Thanks, @Derek F. That's really what I need. Everything works well now.